# 17.04 - Duplicates icons on Desktop since last kernel release 4.10.0-24-generic

Tags: boot, kernel, desktop-environments, 17.04

Since last kernel release I experienced huge lag when booting and even after. It seems it went away but I have duplicates icons on my desktop. 1 series is clickable, not the other though !

The non clickable ones are like included in the background picture !

Sometimes it goes back to normal after rebooting sometimes not. I included a pic of the desktop.

Any idea ?

[image: Pic of my deskop with duplicates icons]

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

-> gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false

See:

```
 https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2286043
```

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my case: there was another Desktop directory in my Desktop directory. Don't know how come it happens! I suppressed it everything went back to normal.